# Using Pointer in PreProcessing in C++

Tags: c++, sdl

I have a pointer in which I keep the window width of an sdl window. I need to use it with preprocesser functions.

I can do:

```
#define something *ScreenWidth
```

but I can't do:

```
#if *ScreenWidth < 900
```

or

```
#if something < 900
```

I know * is not allowed in preprocessors but I need to get ScreenWidth every frame and do "#define"s accordingly. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: No. The preprocessor has no idea what it's operating on beyond just text

Comment: Why using macros for that at all? I don't get the point of your question.

Comment: The preprocessor runs while compiling, not when the program is run. You want to do something based on the screen width of the programmer, not the end user? Why would you want that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know screen width during the compilation so you can't `#define` it. If you have such a problem you should consider redesigning your code, so it could obtain screen width in an initialization step and store it in some global variable.
According to Scott Meyers, you should always prefer compilation to preprocessing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using some macros defined using pointers but I now see why I can't use * with #if. I think I'll redesign my code.

Comment: @bfkjohns It's not just `*` -- you can't do ANYTHING that depends on runtime values in the preprocessor.